# Criar certificado SSL para uso do https no localhost

Tags: php, apache, certificado-digital, ssl

Tentei alguns tutoriais na internet para habilitar o https no meu localhost e até agora não consegui fazer direito, parece que alguma coisa esta quebrada, pois ele aparece como página não segura e a sigla "https://" riscado em vermelho, mas se eu forçar ele funciona; O terminal também fica pedindo um senha a todo instante que imagino ser do certificado. 
O que eu queria é refazer tudo de novo direito, limpar o que fiz antes e aprender o passo a passo certinho, se alguém puder me auxiliar, fico grato.

Estou usando linux/ubuntu16.10

Comment: Você criou ou está comprando esse certificado?

Comment: Quero criar para uso local

Comment: Amigo, costumo seguir este tutorial [https://servidordebian.org/pt/jessie/intranet/ssl_cert/start]. Pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: Valeu @IsaqueFernando creio que vá ajudar sim!

Comment: O caso foi resolvido com esse tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @TalesBreno seria legal explicar melhor na sua resposta como foi que resolveu (não só com o link) pois da forma que ficou, bastava um comentário e não um link como resposta. Se puder fazer a gentileza de explicar ao menos os passos essenciais, fica legal pros outros visitantes com o mesmo problema.

Comment: O caso foi resolvido com o tutorial que eu indiquei na resposta... Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente você não está fazendo nada errado. A falha que indica que a página não é segura aparece porque o certificado é autoassinado (criado por você). Leia [aqui](https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/kb/corrigir-SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER#w_certificado-auto-assinado) um esclarecimento sobre isso. Como você vê, é possível dizer ao `Firefox` que o certificado, apesar de autoassinado, é confiável. Mas a mensagem **sempre** vai aparecer a menos que você compre um certificado assinado por uma instituição certificadora confiável ([mais detalhes](http://www.iti.gov.br/certificacao-digital/como-obter)).

Em suma, para usar certificado criado por você mesmo, vc vai sempre ter que "forçar" o navegador a confiar nele.

Para gerar certificado sem a senha (supondo que você usa `openssl`), basta passar a opção `-nodes` no comando de criação, algo como isso: `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout local_da_key/nome.key -out local_do_certificado/nome.crt`

Essa informação veio [daqui](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04), e em tradução livre, é mais ou menos isso:

> -nodes: Essa opção informa ao OpenSSL que não desejamos proteger nosso arquivo de chave com uma senha. Ter um arquivo de chave protegido por senha atrapalharia a inicialização automática do Apache, pois teríamos que digitar a senha toda vez que o serviço fosse reiniciado.

Acredito que o passo a passo desse tutorial que indiquei é muito bom pra aprender o básico.

Se você tem um domínio público registrado a quer certificação gratuita, vale a pena conhecer https://letsencrypt.org/, que em conjunto com https://certbot.eff.org/ são uma excelente ferramenta (Veja um tutorial para Apache [aqui](https://certbot.eff.org/#debianjessie-apache)).

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava com o mesmo erro e oque resolveu pra mim foi:

1 - Limpar o **cache** do navegador (ctrl+alt+del).

2 - Colocar a **porta** na url, ex.: https://localhost:**443**/projeto...

Obs.: Não sei se resolve em todos os casos, no meu eu segui este tutorial aqui (https://academiawordpress.com.br/usando-https-no-localhost/) pra instalação do certificado no Windows.

Espero que ajude!